# How to Deploy Angular App in SharePoint 2013

Tags: angular, sharepoint, angular6, sharepoint-2013

I have created angular project (Basically a form).How can I deploy that SharePoint 2013?

I have tried building the project with the command ng build but it's not working

Couldn't get proper article/answer for deploying angular app to SharePoint.
I have not used any SP services in the app instead used REST API

Can someone provide me the  information on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample demo to use AngularCLI to build angular app.

After deploying app, run `npm run bundle` to build the app.

Copy the dist files to SharePoint

[image]

Update index.html to pints to these js files.

```
<body>
  <app-angular-demo-web-part description="Hello world!"></app-angular-demo-web-part>
<script src="/SiteAssets/AngularDemo/runtime.js"></script><script src="/SiteAssets/AngularDemo/polyfills-es5.js" nomodule></script><script src="/SiteAssets/AngularDemo/polyfills.js"></script><script src="/SiteAssets/AngularDemo/scripts.js"></script><script src="/SiteAssets/AngularDemo/main.js"></script></body>
```

Link the html file in content editor webpart and result.

[image]

[Refer this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737101/deploying-angular2-project-on-sharepoint-online)